# $videoFeed = $yt->getUserUploads makes the script die

Tags: php, zend-framework, youtube, youtube-api, zend-framework2

I am using a yt-getuseruploads-script that has been working for years, but suddenly it aborts without an error message. It starts like this

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
ignore_user_abort(true);

function anmelden_yt($name,$passwort)
{
$yt_source = 'known';  
$yt_api_key = 'key';
$yt = null;    
$authenticationURL= 'https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin';  
$httpClient = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient(  
$username = $name,  
$password = $passwort,  
$service = 'youtube',  
$client = null,  
$source = $yt_source, // a short string identifying your application  
$loginToken = null,  
$loginCaptcha = null,  
$authenticationURL); 
abschnitt("Login");
return new Zend_Gdata_YouTube($httpClient, $yt_source, NULL, $yt_api_key); 
}


require_once("Zend/Gdata/ClientLogin.php");  
require_once("Zend/Gdata/HttpClient.php");  
require_once("Zend/Gdata/YouTube.php"); 
require_once("Zend/Gdata/App/MediaFileSource.php");  
require_once("Zend/Gdata/App/HttpException.php");  
require_once('Zend/Uri/Http.php');
require_once 'Zend/Loader.php'; 
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_YouTube'); 
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_AuthSub');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin'); 

echo "1<br>";  
$yt = anmelden_yt($name,$pass);
echo "2<br>";
$videoFeed = $yt->getUserUploads('Google');
sleep(0.5);
echo "3<br>";


    @ob_flush();
@flush();

?>
```

Problem is, 3 is never being printed, output is

```
1
2
```

So even though error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE); I get no error message and nothing but the mentioned result. There is no premature break or die.

Comment: Try real debugging and go into the function. XDebug or the likes of it. Can't really help without concrete errors. But debugging will help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that it's a time limit error ?
Try to do :

```
ini_set('display_errors','1');
```

at first to see if there's errors

Comment: That helped. Great. PS: I never wrote about a time limit error.

Comment: Next question is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245998/fatal-error-uncaught-exception-zend-gdata-app-httpexception-with-message-exp